# Error extraction XML in PHP

Tags: php, jquery, xml

I need to extract two data from an XML file. I am using this script:

Canzone in onda:

```
<?php
$estrazioneAPI = new SimpleXMLElement('http://api.radionomy.com/currentsong.cfm?radiouid=0523cc62-e00c-485e-8e65-aea2aa37702a&apikey=b3ec3722-a1e6-44af-9d95-cb97ade2f4dc&callmeback=yes&type=xml&cover=yes&previous=yes.xml', NULL, TRUE);
if(false === $estrazioneAPI)
{
  echo "test";
}
$canzoni = $estrazioneAPI->xpath("//tracks");
if(count($canzoni) > 0) {
    foreach($canzoni as $track) {
        $titolo = $track->track->title;
        $artista = $track->track->artists;
        if($titolo == '' AND $artista == ''){
        echo "Nessuna canzone in onda";
        }else if($titolo == '' AND $artista != ''){
                echo "$artista - Titolo non riconosciuto";
        }else if($titolo != '' AND $artista == ''){
                echo "Artista non riconosciuto - $titolo";
            }else{
                 echo $artista . " - " . $titolo;
            }
    }
}



?>
</marquee></i>
```

Going to the page where I put this script works correctly, the problem is that on another page I put this to update the data every 15 seconds:

```
<script>
$(document).observe('dom:loaded', function() {
  new Ajax.PeriodicalUpdater('canzoneInOnda', '../api_webbo/canzone_in_onda.php', { frequency: 15 });
});
</script>
<div id="canzoneInOnda"></div>
```

Everything is OK except that this writing comes out from time to time:

Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'String could not be parsed as XML

Then at the next update it returns to work normally...
How could I solve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This because your returned XML is not valid. You should use `try-catch` and write log when an exception happens. And, we should not use `SimpleXMLElement` to get the url resource directly.

```
<?php

try {
    $url = 'http://api.radionomy.com/currentsong.cfm?radiouid=0523cc62-e00c-485e-8e65-aea2aa37702a&apikey=b3ec3722-a1e6-44af-9d95-cb97ade2f4dc&callmeback=yes&type=xml&cover=yes&previous=yes.xml';
    $ch = curl_init($url);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "GET");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    $estrazioneAPI = new SimpleXMLElement($result);
    //Bla bla your code...


} catch (Throwable $exception) {
    //Write log exception
    //echo $exception->getMessage();
    //var_dump($result);
}
```